# Crear/ejecutar un jar de spring boot y ejecutarlo con shell?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Buen día a todos. hago esta pregunta ya que con spring boot he notado la facilidad de hacer una conexión a una base de datos tanto usando JPA o Mybatis.

Quiero crear un jar que solo ejecute por sh, el jar solo hará consultas a la base de datos y obtener los datos para generar reportes en excel  y enviarlos por mail.

En la clase principal solo implemente el CommandLineRunner
y sobreescribio el metodo run y luego invoco el metodo que quiero.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CrearReportesApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    
   @Autowire
   GenerarReporteService generarReporte;    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CrearReportesApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        System.out.println("Iniciando proceso");
        generarReporte.iniciarProceso();
        
    }

}
```

Como paso final creo el jar. y al correrlo desde cmd con `java -jar inventario.jar`
Me aparece un mensaje diciendo: `no hay ningún atributo de manifiesto principal en inventario.jar`

Es aqui donde empieza mi duda, si es posible hacer estas operaciones en spring boot. Alguna ida de como lo podria crear?

Comment: El problema está en que no sabemos cómo creas el JAR. EL error dice que no le estás dando entrypoint a Java para ejecutar el JAR.

Comment: Entonces como es?

Comment: Primero edita tu pregunta y cuéntanos cómo armas el jar, heh.

Answer (score 1):

este error lo tienes porque cuando generas el archivo jar, no estas indicando cual es tu clase que contiene el método main, con netbeans o eclipse se puede hacer al momento de generar el jar, se indica la clase con el main para que el IDE lo agregue al archivo MANIFEST.MF, o si estas trabajando con maven, puedes agregar lo siguiente a tu archivo pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    //Sufijo que se le agregara al fichero JAR ejecutable
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        //Aqui se establece el nombre de la clase principal
                        <mainClass>com.test.main.ClassMethodMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Luego de esa configuración basta con que hagas un build con maven, luego el package y tu jar estará funcionando correctamente, espero te sea de ayuda.